# Make a select form using images

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on my site and I want that user could choose answer to formular by clicking on the image representing the category. For example, click on ball is equal to `<option value="sport">Sport<option>`

So, is it possibile to select option from formular by clicking on image, instead normal select list?

The Internet is full of solutions showing how to add a mini-picture next to option from list, but this is not what i am looking for.

If the question repeats, or there is a solution in internet, i would be grateful for link

Comment: Please share how much you've tried. The question is not that clear. At least share an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is better explained with Teletubbies.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#images img').click(function() {
    $('#teletubbies').val($(this).attr('id'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="teletubbies" name="teletubbies">
  <option value="yellow">Laa-Laa</option>
  <option value="green">Dipsy</option>
  <option value="purple">Tinky Winky</option>
</select> 
<div id="images">
 <img id="yellow" src="https://apprecs.org/ios/images/app-icons/256/ba/1071811770.jpg" />
 <img id="green" src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple30/v4/99/95/68/999568bc-1ae5-1b73-5a17-b15edb3d0106/source/256x256bb.jpg" />
 <img id="purple" src="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple18/v4/17/7f/c7/177fc7b6-62ed-6132-7641-ada29f5d5f7e/source/256x256bb.jpg" />
</div>
```